# use gsm as keyboard for raspberry pi via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I want ro use my phone to connect to my raspberry pi 3 via bluetooth. Now I don't know how, but that is not my question.

I want to use my phone keyboard (just the keyboard) as a wireless keyboard for my raspberry pi. So I have a touchscreen and want to be able to type on the screen. But that didn't work out since I use the pi as a standalone app without the possibility to use the gui of raspbian pixel.

So I want to be able to use my phone's keyboard in the app. So when I type text on my phone, it appears in the selected box.

Is this possible and how? I don't want to use a vnc.

Comment: Does this app fit the bill? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inspiredandroid.linuxcontrolcenter&hl=en

promotes all the things you require it to do, and it seems to be able to do it via ssh (so no need to install other software on your rpi)

Comment: That is sort of what I want. The only thing here is, I can't select raspbian... so how should I use it then?

Comment: Select debian. Raspbian is based on the debian distro